# how to check if the model in ML is good for the dataset when you apply the model on real data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I have a python script that classify text positive or negative.
I have a dataset i split it to train and test data after i done a pre-process to the text  i got

- 91% accuracy on trained data
- 87% accuracy on tested data

When i tried on real data it give **20% accuracy** where is the error ??

Trained data

```
Accuracy: 91.459%
Best parameters set found on development set:

{'bow__ngram_range': (1, 2), 'tfidf__use_idf': True}

Optimized model achieved an ROC of:  0.9998
```

Tested data

```
accuracy score:  0.8704919797610077


confusion matrix: 
 [[3920  699]
 [ 504 4166]]


              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.89      0.85      0.87      4619
           1       0.86      0.89      0.87      4670

   micro avg       0.87      0.87      0.87      9289
   macro avg       0.87      0.87      0.87      9289
weighted avg       0.87      0.87      0.87      9289
```

I am using **Logistic Regression** as a ML model  and using **TfIdf**  and **cross validation**.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn import model_selection

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
    cross_val = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42)
    # create pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('bow', CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii',
                                stop_words=['english'],
                                lowercase=True)),  # strings to token integer counts
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),  # integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
        ('classifier', LogisticRegression(C=15.075475376884423,penalty="l2")),  
    ])
    
    parameters = {'bow__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
                  'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
                    
                 }
    
       clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters, cv=cross_val, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, scoring= 'roc_auc')
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one case to check model is good or not. A bunch of reasons/suggestions from me:

1. Distribution of your data in train and test set
2. If the data distribution is not balanced, tree models can give better results.
3. Actual data and train+test data should be in same distribution (at least similar otherwise it is like : you train with cats and check for dogs)
4. Train and Test accuracy difference normally gives a hint about the performance of model
5. If your train dataset is to small, it can also cause this
   result(actual %20acc). You can apply data augmentation and try
   again.

My guess, your actual data is not similar with train/test sets.

Comment: ok lets take each point.
1 . train data 80% test data 20%
2. data is balanced between positive  and negative  labels
5.the dataset is about 46000 records

i think your guess is right but how to get a  similar dataset  to the actual data?

Comment: You need to use same source for train/test data. If your actual data from twitter, use twitter data. Actual data: A special academic publications, use data from same academic domain. Otherwise with ML methods, it is hard to solve that. Or you can collect more data from different type of sources and use DL models. (ML models not good with huge datasets)

Comment: i am using a dataset for twitter in training and testing and the real data is twitter data so why there is this gap in my model ?

Comment: It can be language differences, train/test data can be too old. Twitter data can also have many inner topics, sarcasm, typos in words. You should check your samples in data and try to detect with your eyes. If you can clearly say, positive and negative tweets when you read, ml can find it.

Comment: language is english---trained data not too old it includes sarcasm and typos but i pre processed the text and the amount of sarcasm text is not very big so i thought that  the accuracy must be a lot more of 20%

Comment: Did you check a few samples, Can you say that is positve or negative, clearly. If so, in theoretical part, I coulnd't find anything wrong. Sorry out of ideas :)

Comment: i will add some sample of text with the prediction